# I am getting error "the input data is not a complete block" in decryption using AES/CBC/Pkcs7 algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, streamreader, aescryptoserviceprovider

```cs
public static string Decryptss(string cipherText, string symkey)
{
    try
    {
        return DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(symkey), new byte[16]);
    }
    catch (CryptographicException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message == "The input data is not a complete block.")
        {
            // This is plaintext
            return cipherText;
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
    catch (FormatException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message == "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string." || ex.Message.StartsWith("The input is not a valid Base-64 string"))
        {
            // This is plaintext
            return cipherText;
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
}

public static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
    // Check arguments.
    if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
    if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
    if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

    // Declare the string used to hold
    // the decrypted text.
    string plaintext = null;

    // Create an Aes object
    // with the specified key and IV.
    using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        aesAlg.Key = Key;
        aesAlg.IV = IV;

        // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

        // Create the streams used for decryption.
        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
        {
            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                {

                    // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting  stream
                    // and place them in a string.
                    // Here I am Getting Error.
                    plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return plaintext;
}
```

I was tried with different - different methods. But that is not work for me.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614178/aes-encryption-error-the-input-data-is-not-a-complete-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614178/aes-encryption-error-the-input-data-is-not-a-complete-block)

Comment: Not reproducible, i.e. the code works for me as long as the appropriate data is used. Maybe your data is corrupted, inconsistent or an incompatible encryption logic was applied. Post the encryption code and complete test data.